# Слишком долгое выполнение SQL запроса (таймаут)

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework-core

Используется MS SQL Server (Microsoft Azure), запрос выполняется из ASP .NET Core приложения (EF Core).

Таблица с 16 колонками, в том числе колонкой ID (`Guid`, PK) и колонкой CreationDate (`DateTime`, есть Index).

В таблице обычно очень много записей, но сейчас я сократил их количество до 23 тысяч (тестовая БД).

Мне нужно удалять старые записи из таблицы. Если я пытаюсь удалить даже **одну** запись через EF Core (методом `.Remove()` и затем `SaveChangesAsync()`), срабатывает таймаут. Пробовал делать удаление через `.Database.ExecuteSqlRawAsync("DELETE FROM MyTableName WHERE CreationDate < DATEADD(day, -1, GETDATE())")` - всё равно таймаут.

Выполнил этот же самый SQL запрос через SQL Server Management Studio - он выполнился, но это заняло 33 минуты 58 секунд (23294 записи было удалено). После того как в базе осталось меньше чем 200 записей, то SQL запрос из EF Core тоже стал работать (правда удалять нечего, так что по факту 0 записей удаляет на данный момент, но таймаута нет).

БД в Azure имеет `Tier S1 (20 DTUs)` - может этого действительно мало? Или всё таки тут закралась какая-то ошибка? Я раньше работал только с небольшими базами, так что может упускаю что-то очевидное.

Comment: за 33 минуты можно в экселе вручную таблицу просмотреть )

Comment: Индекс по `CreationDate` есть?

Comment: да, есть. ну, я на самом деле вроде разобрался уже - надо индекс перестраивать постоянно, у меня постоянно старые записи удаляются, а новые добавляются, индекс устаревает.